# Links to files in assets not working in github project page using jekyll

Tags: jekyll, assets, github-pages

I am setting up a github project pages blog using jekyll, and the links to my `assets` files do not work properly. I have seen several other posts with similar issues, but none seem to apply to my case. Before marking as duplicate, please check that I have not already tried the solution suggested in the other question.

When trying to add an image to my post the image does not show. When I try to link to a pdf for download I get a dead link (as in `http://nikosdaniilidis/github.io/assets/all-pdf/Daniilidis2014-surface-noise.pdf`)

I tried the following configurations:

#### Case 0

In `_config.yml`

```
    baseurl: "/projectname"`
    url: "http://username/github.io/projectname"
```

In `_posts/some-post`

```
    ![image here]({{ site.url }}/assets/path/to/image.png)
    [pdf here]({{ site.url }}/assets/path/to/some.pdf)
```

Resulting link paths (not working):

```
    http://nikosdaniilidis/github.io/altblog/assets/all-pdf/Daniilidis2014-surface-noise.pdf
```

#### Case 1

In `_config.yml`

```
    baseurl: "/projectname"`
    url: "http://username/github.io"
```

In `_posts/some-post`

```
    ![image here]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/path/to/image.png)
    [pdf here]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/path/to/some.pdf)
```

Resulting link paths (not working):

```
    http://nikosdaniilidis/github.io/assets/all-pdf/Daniilidis2014-surface-noise.pdf
```

#### Case 2

In `_config.yml`

```
    baseurl: "/projectname"`
    url: "http://username/github.io"
```

In `_posts/some-post`

```
    ![image here]({{ site.baseurl }}{{post.url}}/assets/path/to/image.png)
    [pdf here]({{ site.baseurl }}{{post.url}}/assets/path/to/some.pdf)
```

Resulting link paths (not working):

```
    http://nikosdaniilidis/github.io/assets/all-pdf/Daniilidis2014-surface-noise.pdf
```

I am running out of ideas and really appreciate some help! Here is the [repo](https://github.com/nikosdaniilidis/altblog), and here is the resulting [page](http://nikosdaniilidis.github.io/altblog/) (look under [Test links and other asset material](http://nikosdaniilidis.github.io/altblog/jekyll/update/2014/10/02/Test-Links.html) post, currently configured with the last of the above cases).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github pages user repository url pattern is `username.github.io` and NOT `username/github.io`

Try :

```
url: http://nikosdaniilidis.github.io
baseurl: /altblog
```

Comment: Thank you! Gosh I had been looking at this for so long I could not see before my eyes...I'm glad it was something that trivial!

Comment: And your question was perfect :  
 - search for solutions  
 - give a code repository  
  
Very good question !

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with the kasper jekyll theme. I guess that not all themes support project mode. Or they do but you have to rewrite some of the liquid syntax to use the baseurl etc. The kasper theme worked right out of the gate in a fresh organisation site.